# Applying modulo function on MD5 hash

Tags: md5, consistent-hashing

I have a use case to evenly distribute input strings into ‘n’ buckets. If I apply MD5 algorithm to generate a hash of the string and then apply modulo function will it result in even distribution of input into ‘n’ buckets?

Otherwise what are other mechanisms to achieve even distribution of strings ?

Comment: What information do you have about the input? Do you know it beforehand?

Comment: No they are some random strings and we don’t know them beforehand

Comment: Can you give the inputs individual IDs, preferable some kind of auto increment value?